# How to Filter Mac Address from Specified String using Regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match

Actually i have the String Like Following?

```
Physical Address Transport Name =================== 
==========================================================
00-1F-29-A8-CA-54 Media disconnected 
00-21-5C-68-BB-17 \Device\Tcpip_{1A76BCB8-6BD0-45AA-85B0-3016C3F82A5B}
```

Please Help me to to filter only mac address from the above string. Thanks you.

Comment: Hi Dinesh: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using `preg_match_all` function and POSIX character class `[:xdigit:]`(will match all hexadecimal digits):

```
// $str is your initial string
preg_match_all("/\b[[:xdigit:]]{2}-[[:xdigit:]]{2}-[[:xdigit:]]{2}-[[:xdigit:]]{2}-[[:xdigit:]]{2}-[[:xdigit:]]{2}\b/su", $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00-1F-29-A8-CA-54
    [1] => 00-21-5C-68-BB-17
)
```

Comment: This doesn't always work.  For example `arp -an` could return aa:aa:aa:a:1:aa instead of aa:aa:aa:0a:01:aa